# How to solve unable to find valid certification path to requested target on production?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a JKS which I need for authentication to start making use of a SOAP webservice.
On my local machine (windows) all is working fine. For add the following to my startup parameters for Tomcat in Eclipse:

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path\to\keystore\keystore.jks"   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passwordC -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks
```

In production (ubuntu) we have the following:

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks"
```

I'm using Java 1.7.0.80 and Tomcat 7.0.61

When I want to connect with the SOAP webservice I get the following Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://www.correosexpress.com/wsp/services/GrabacionEnvio: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1359)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1343)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I checked the Java versions, tomcat versions.
I also checked if the path to the JKS is correct, which it is.

On my local machine, I did not install any other certificates manually. i.e I don't have any entry in the cacerts which is related to the content in the jks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check with java keytool that your certificate is present in certificates list.
2. Check that your java home and your jre are the same. In ubuntu it possible to have java_home with one version of java and default jre with other version(check this command - update-alternatives --config java)
3. If you added certificate to the correct version of java and it's present in certs list check that you use correct version of certificate.

Comment: Do you mean that the certificate must be present in cacerts?

Comment: No, in ubuntu cacerts certificates will be ignored by java. I mean java keystore